# Cost of reflection: WPF

Tags: c#, reflection

I have implemented an extension helper to load a WPF usercontrol to a window dynamically. (MyButton is in another assembly).

This helper is in a class lib that is used in all my projects. The idea is to save on re-coding this operation and keep the client code cleaner.

I would like a second pair of eyes (or more) to let me know if the cost of this to too high.

Thanks.

```
 public static Window OpenUserControl(this MyButton button, string controlName, string title)
        {
            //      
            object uControl;
            try
            {
                Type newType = button.GetType().Assembly.GetType(controlName,true,true);
                uControl = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                throw;
            }


            // launch the usercontrol as a window.
            Window form = new Window
            {
                Title = title,
                Content = uControl,
                ShowInTaskbar = false
            };
            return form;
        }
```

Comment: Do you *have* to pass the control type by name? Any reason you don't just accept it as a `Type`, or even make it generic? You definitely shouldn't have that try/catch block though - it's just cruft.

Comment: Seems like a good topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't imagine that you are opening so many windows that this would ever matter. You might be able to improve it, as suggested above, but the reflection aspect is not a concern.

Comment: @austinwernli thanks, ill do that next time.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I could pass in the type for sure.

Comment: @Jay I am only opening one window in this case. In others it is two, and they are on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the type at compile-time, you'd be a lot better off making this generic:

```
// Possibly add more generic constraints to T?
public static Window OpenUserControl<T>(string title)
    where T : new()
{
    return new Window
    {
        Title = title,
        Content = new T(),
        ShowInTaskbar = false
    };
}
```

This is likely to be a *bit* faster than finding the type by reflection, although another option would be to cache a delegate to call the parameterless constructor - more work, but much faster in my experience. You could do that via a nested generic class, caching a `Func<T>` or `Func<object>` in the class as a static field.

Only you can really tell whether this is fast enough - but it should be easy enough to benchmark, and I very much doubt that it's going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: I passed in 'button' as the OpenUsercontrol is in a different assembly. I needed a reference to find the 'usercontrol' I wanted. Thanks for the change.

Comment: @Arnej65: Ah, I see - so no need when you're passing in the type itself via generics. Will edit. (Although even in the original code, unless you were actually going to be passing in subtypes of `MyButton` which were in a different assembly from `MyButton`, you could just use `typeof(MyButton)` for simplicity.)